# Change color to each contour given a property with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the following by using matplotlib. I have a contour plot but I would like to change the intensity of each level by a given property. Let say, you have a contour plot and there is a vector also assigned to each point and I would like to plot the line of the contour of one colour if the vector is pointing up and a different colour if the vector is pointing down. Would it be possible? thanks in advance!

Comment: Put at least a draft code. How your data is and some pseudo code of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pseudo code that barely works, but the figure is not coming so nicely....I did clean this part of my code and let me put it here..

given x,y which define the grid points and z the grid of the 3D data

I create the contour plot

```
cont = plt.contour(x, y, z, linewidths=0.7, colors='k', linestyles='solid')
```

Now let me assume I have a property also in the same grid, I called gx

```
paths = cont.collections[0].get_paths() 
verts = [xx.vertices for xx in paths]
pts = np.concatenate(verts)

plt.scatter(pts[::6,0],pts[::6,1],s=100,edgecolor='none',alpha=1.0,c=gx[::6], marker="s")
```

Thanks!